# C# Encoding.UTF8.GetString return Unicode .Net6

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I'm trying to store a password encrypted with the System.Security.Cryptography package. I want to store the encrypted password in an Environment Variable, but when converting the byte[], returned by the Protect() method, into a string with Encoding.UTF8.ToString(string) i just get unicode characters and the program crashes when trying to print the Environment Variable value with the PrintValues method:

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
namespace Crrypto
{
    class Program
    {
        static byte[] s_additionalEntropy = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello");
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a simple byte array containing data to be encrypted.
            byte[] secret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password");
            

            //Encrypt the data.
            byte[] encryptedSecret = Protect(secret);
            var store = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedSecret);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("passwordLA",store);
            Console.WriteLine("The encrypted byte array is:");
            PrintValues(encryptedSecret);

            // Decrypt the data and store in a byte array.
            var secretFromEnv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("passwordLA");
            var loaded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretFromEnv);
            byte[] originalData = Unprotect(loaded);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}The original data is:", Environment.NewLine);
            PrintValues(originalData);
        }

        public static byte[] Protect(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                // Encrypt the data using DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser. The result can be decrypted
                // only by the same current user.
                return ProtectedData.Protect(data, s_additionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
            }
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data was not encrypted. An error occurred.");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static byte[] Unprotect(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                //Decrypt the data using DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser.
                return ProtectedData.Unprotect(data, s_additionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
            }
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data was not decrypted. An error occurred.");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static void PrintValues(Byte[] myArr)
        {
            foreach (Byte i in myArr)
            {
                Console.Write("\t{0}", (char)i);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Store it as a Base64 string instead of converting the byte values to characters.

Comment: You should never call `Encoding.GetString` unless you're passing in *plain text* which has been encoding with the specified encoding. Otherwise it's like storing a blob of arbitrary data in a file which *happens* to have an extension of .mp3 and expecting to be able to play it as valid audio. (As an aside, I'd also strongly recommend against writing `UnicodeEncoding.UTF8` - the property is defined in the `Encoding` class, and `UnicodeEncoding` is effectively for UTF-16.)

Comment: @Jesse thank you, that just works fine!

Comment: You should post that as an answer, not as part of the question. You are welcome to answer your own question

Answer (score -1):

Changed Code to following, so now it works:

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
namespace Crrypto
{
    class Program
    {
        static byte[] s_additionalEntropy = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello");//{ 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a simple byte array containing data to be encrypted.
            byte[] secret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password");
           

            //Encrypt the data.
            byte[] encryptedSecret = Protect(secret);
            
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("passwordLA",Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedSecret));
            Console.WriteLine("The encrypted byte array is:");
            PrintValues(encryptedSecret);

            // Decrypt the data and store in a byte array.
            var secretFromEnv = Convert.FromBase64String(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("passwordLA"));
           
            byte[] originalData = Unprotect(secretFromEnv);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}The original data is:", Environment.NewLine);
            PrintValues(originalData);
        }

        public static byte[] Protect(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                // Encrypt the data using DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser. The result can be decrypted
                // only by the same current user.
                return ProtectedData.Protect(data, s_additionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
            }
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data was not encrypted. An error occurred.");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static byte[] Unprotect(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                //Decrypt the data using DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser.
                return ProtectedData.Unprotect(data, s_additionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
            }
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data was not decrypted. An error occurred.");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static void PrintValues(Byte[] myArr)
        {
            foreach (Byte i in myArr)
            {
                Console.Write("\t{0}", (char)i);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).